# Use "find" to select a zip file and deplace them with mv

Tags: bash, find, mv

First Im beginning on Linux,
I try to select zip files only and move them in an other folder, but it's not working :/
Please help Im completely loosed.

The code:

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" | xargs mv /home/maxime/SAVES;
```

Answer (score 1):

With either bash or zshell you can use

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec mv {} /path/to/target/directory/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks ! It work

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you just specify that `mv` should treat the destination as a target **directory** with the `-t` option.

`find . -type f -name "*.zip" | xargs mv -t /home/maxime/SAVES;`